# React inline css class without import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a dir with css files which i want to import them in a way that i can use them as follows,
without import it at the top of the file

```
<div className={`chartbar`}
```

My files that i want to import them inline they are all in the dir 'src/app/containers/chart/styles'. The follow seems that is not working

```
  {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/containers/chart/styles'),
        ],
        use: [
            {loader: 'style-loader'},
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true
                }
            },
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if I have correctly understood your question. But what I think is that you want to apply css module conditionally using inline css without importing a css module. Yes it can be easily done in React. The way it could be done is by creating a Java Script object of the css properties and then applying it when you need.

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
const wrapper = {
   display: 'flex',
   flexDirection: 'column',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   width: '100%',
   padding: '50px',
   color: '#444',
   border: '1px solid #1890ff',
 };
 function Print(){
 return(
 <div style={wrapper}><h1>
 Hello World
 </h1>
 </div>
 )
 ReactDOM.render(<Print/>,document.getElementById("root"))
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Hope that helps!